# Why Hindu is not connected to other hindu but Every Hindu is connected with Lord Kirshna?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, non-hindu

People claim that only Hindu stand against the Hindu and the hindus are always connected to Lord Krishna but not with each other. They are never together but they all are one united with God Krishna only.

Comment: it's like tubelight in hall and bulb in kitchen. both are in same house, and both give light, but they're connected to each other only through electricity wiring of house. that's why Hindus generally don't go out to streets to protest. their connection is directly with Bhagavan inside heart.